# Why does this django queryset object become a list when I slice it? python

Tags: python, django-queryset, slice

I'm stumped, please someone point me in the correct direction:

All the objects in the tuple are queryset objects that I am checking the existence of

```
existing = []
for i in (obj for obj in (mao,ddo,mo,bo,ao,ro) if obj.exists()):
    existing.append(i)
```

I then execute the following line of code in an effort to pull out the QSO's in sequence and perform opperations on them

```
existing_len = len(existing)
if existing_len > 0:
    c = 0
    for i in existing:
        cc = 0
        while cc < len(i):

            r = type(i)
            o = i[cc:cc+1]
            q = type(o)
            d = o.values()[0]
```

but i am given an error

```
'd = o.values()[0]    list' object has no attribute 'values'
```

I don't understand what's happening though, I am slicing the queryset in order to retain `QSO.values()` because I want to extract the dictionary.
If I `type(i)` it tells me i'm dealing with a `<class 'django.db.models.query.QuerySet'>` but once I slice it, it becomes a list but how?
I've tried to recreate the error on the command line but I'm always given a QSO after the slice. Can anyone help please :)

```
i   [<match: match object>]
r   <class 'django.db.models.query.QuerySet'>
o   [<match: match object>]
q   <type 'list'>
mo  [<match: match object>]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you are trying to do, because your variable names make no sense. Please use descriptive names.

As soon as you do `len(i)`, the [queryset is evaluated](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated), in addition here `i[cc:cc+1]` you are also evaluating the QS, converting it into a list.

Just think about it for a second, you are asking it to go from `cc` to `cc+1`, it can't know what `cc+1` is unless it executes the query, because you may be going out of bounds for the result set size.

You also have some unnecessary code, try slimming down your logic to just the following:

```
existing = list(obj for obj in (mao,ddo,mo,bo,ao,ro) if obj.exists())
for i in existing:
    cc = i.count() # Its still a QS here.
    # Now do whatever here
```

Comment: Than you very much :) Sorry about the non-descriptive variables, I've been staring at this for hours and it was a frantic copy and paste job. Thank you for the detailed explanation :)

Comment: Hello again, just ran `existing = list(obj for obj in (mao,ddo,mo,bo,ao,ro) if obj.exists())` in the interpreter and was given the error `TypeError: 'list' object is not callable`. Is this to be expected? Just thought I'd ask before I get home to test it, thanks :)

Comment: This means somewhere in your code you have `list = 5` or something else; you have assigned the name `list` to something other than the built-in function `list`.

Answer (score 1):

A QuerySet evaluates to a `list` when [slicing with steps](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/queries/#limiting-querysets). Using normal slicing does not.